# Program considers two equal doubles to be different

Tags: java, compare, equals

I am comparing two Doubles:

```
37.4238777160645
```

and

```
37.4238777160645
```

But Java does not consider them to be equal.  I am comparing them in the following manner

```
if(object1.getLatitude()!=object2.getLatitude()){
    fail("objects are not equal "+object1.getLatitude()+":"+object2.getLatitude());
}
```

resulting in the following fail:

```
junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: objects are not equal  37.4238777160645:37.4238777160645
```

I don't understand why - Please advise.

Comment: What is the type returned from `getLatitude()`?

Comment: Can you try with `if(!object1.getLatitude().equals(object2.getLatitude())){`

Comment: @AndroidAddict are you sure it is `double` and not `Double`?

Comment: `double` or `Double`?

Comment: Are  you sure it's not `Double`? (capital "D"?)

Comment: @Pshemo  that would require that I implement the equals and use the same method I am performing with the same issue.

Comment: Okay it's Double.  Why would that make a difference?

Comment: Great comment, OP... love it.

Comment: @AndroidAddict Difference is that for non primitive types `==` compares equality of references, and `equals` checks equality of state of object (its value).

Comment: the difference is primitive type vs. Object @AndroidAddict

Comment: Will someone please find a duplicate and put this to rest? I am ashamed to admit that I couldn't find it.

Comment: @MarkoTopolnik found it ;-)

Comment: @AndroidAddict In future, when people ask you questions about your code, please answer them diligently and correctly. Saying it returned `double` when actually it returned `Double` just caused a flurry of comments/questions and wasted everybody's time.

Comment: @donfuxx Thanks, voted to close with that one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should use [java.lang.Double.compare()](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#compare%28double,%20double%29)  :

```
Double.compare(object1.getLatitude(), object2.getLatitude())
```

so you wil have :

```
if(Double.compare(object1.getLatitude(), object2.getLatitude()) != 0){
   fail("objects are not equal "+object1.getLatitude()+":"+object2.getLatitude());
}
```

Comment: Your example should be != 0 since if they are identical the compare method would return the difference between the two values.  If they are identical, the return from compare is therefore 0 and != would be something not 0.

Comment: Edited answer as you suggested, I should have used `!=` instead of `==`.

Answer (score 3):

The issue has already been pointed out. But if you are using junit, it would be simpler to use the appropriate method:

```
assertEquals(object1.getLatitude(), object2.getLatitude());
```

or

```
assertEquals(object1.getLatitude(), object2.getLatitude(), 0.001d);
```

instead of using `fail`. That would also solve your issue.

Answer (score 2):

Objects should be compared with `.equals` and not `==`. By `==` you're comparing the *references*, which are *not* the same since you return a different object each time.

Use [`Double#equals`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Double.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) to compare the *values*.

Comment: I am comparing the `values` of property in the object, not the objects themselves

Comment: @TimB Are you sure `double` cannot handle `37.4238777160645`? I tested it and it *worked*. Please check again.

Comment: @AndroidAddict You mentioned that `getLatitude` returns a `Double`, which is an *object* and not a primitive. So you're comparing *references*.

Comment: @MarounMaroun yes, I sit corrected.

Answer (score 1):

When applied to objects, the `==` operator returns `true` only when both operands are the *same object*.

Your method returns `Double` *objects*, so each call will produce a new object, and comparing them using `==` will always be `false`.

Use `.equals()`, which compares *values* of the `Doubles`:

```
if (!object1.getLatitude().equals(object2.getLatitude()))
```

Alternatively, change you methods to return `double` instead of `Double`, and your current code will work.

Answer (score 0):

Floating point comparison in may programming languages should always take the form of

```
if(a-b op c)
```

where `a` and `b` are the numbers being compared and `c` being the threshold and `op` is either `>` or

> <

.

This is because floating point representation in binary to not map directly to what is printed.